# Bpel if else schema xml

Tags: xml, if-statement, schema, bpel

I tried to place an if condition in my xml scheme for the boolean elements :  ProductIDStatus, ReOrderStatus. Basically if the Stock value is more than 10 than the status of both element 1, else 0.

I created the following code however I still receive the erros messages. Could you please help me with it?

```
<xsd:complexType name="checkResponseType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Stock" type="xsd:decimal" />
<xsd:element name="ProductIDStatus" type="xsd:boolean" >
<xsd:assign name="if (@Stock > '10')
then @ProductIDStatus = 1
else if (@Stock < '10')
then @ProductIDStatus = 0"/>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ReOrderStatus" type="xsd:boolean" >
<xsd:assign name="if (@Stock > '10')
then @ReOrderStatus = 1
else if (@Stock < '10')
then @ReOrderStatus = 0"/>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Mode" type="tns:ModeType" />
<xsd:choice>
<xsd:element name="Email" type="tns:EmailType" minOccurs="0" />
<xsd:element name="Service" type="tns:ServiceType" minOccurs="0" />
</xsd:choice>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed any logic into the XSD. The XSD defines the data model of the SOAP messages exchanged from and to your BPEL process and any variable types you might need in your BPEL process. You can also define several XSDs.

This, the XSD does not have any  elements.

Now the question is what your goal is that you want to accomplish. If you want these flags sent by the caller of your process or do you want your process to "calculate" these flags?

In the former case, just remove your  elements from the WSDL.

In the latter case, remove the  and  elements and define two variables in your BPEL process that are typed xsd:boolean. You can then use BPEL ifs to assign the correct value to your flags.

Comment: thanks for you answer! it looks here I cannot paste correctly the code thus I published the question below;) thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

thanks for you answer!
So it could be something like this?:
For the element from xml schema:

```
<xsd:element name="ReOrderStatus" type="xsd:boolean" />
```

Bpel condition:

```
<bpel:if name=" ReOrderStatus">
<bpel:condition>$CheckStockWSResponse.Stock > '10'       </bpel:condition>
then $CheckStockWSResponse.ReOrderStatus  =  1
<elseif>
<bpel:condition>$CheckStockWSResponse.Stock < '10'   </bpel:condition>
 then $CheckStockWSResponse.ReOrderStatus  =  0
</elseif>
</bpel:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the BPEL syntax is very much different. Also you don't want to declare variables in your message, so delete the element from the schema.

Instead create a BPEL variable

```
<bpel:variables>
  <bpel:variable name="ReOrderStatus" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</bpel:variables>
```

Then you need to set the value of this variable. In your case it can be done quite easily by storing the boolean result of comparing your Stock to your amount:

```
<bpel:assign name="Check_Reorder_Stock">
  <bpel:copy>
    <bpel:from>$CheckStockWSResponse/ns:Stock &gt;= 10</bpel:from>
    <bpel:to variable="ReOrderStatus"/>
  </bpel:copy>
</bpel:assign>
```

If you really want to use s then it would look like this:

```
<bpel:if name="Check_Reorder_Stock">
  <bpel:condition>$CheckStockWSResponse/ns:Stock &gt;= 10</bpel:condition>
  <bpel:assign aei:id="141215246986100626" name="Reorder_Needed">
    <bpel:copy>
      <bpel:from>
        <bpel:literal>true</bpel:literal>
      </bpel:from>
      <bpel:to variable="ReOrderStatus"/>
    </bpel:copy>
  </bpel:assign>
  <bpel:else>
    <bpel:assign name="No_Reorder_Needed">
      <bpel:copy>
        <bpel:from>
          <bpel:literal>false</bpel:literal>
        </bpel:from>
        <bpel:to variable="ReOrderStatus"/>
      </bpel:copy>
    </bpel:assign>
  </bpel:else>
</bpel:if>
```

But in general you should have a look at some BPEL introduction first before proceeding. Typically your BPEL server will have some.